# nslookup/host parsing PHP

Tags: php, parsing, exec, hostname, nslookup

I'm trying to resolve a hostname in PHP and can't use the builtin `gethostbyname` function because it doesn't support a timeout option, therefore i'm trying to deal with that problem by looking up the hostname with `nslookup` or `host`. The Problem is that these Functions/Programs don't return the plain result but something like

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.de
Address: 173.194.35.159
Name:   google.de
Address: 173.194.35.151
Name:   google.de
Address: 173.194.35.152
```

Does anybody know a fast function in PHP to parse that so it just returns the first IP Adress? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression could be improved but it will do the trick.

If your output is in $lines then you can use

```
preg_match('/Address: ([0-9\.]*).*/', $lines, $matches);
```

Then the first match will be stored in

```
$matches[1]
```

Comment: That will fail for IPv6. Use `[0-9a-f.:]` to make it work for both protocol versions. Oh, and you don't need to escape `.` inside a character class.

Comment: The regex above has not worked for me, but dns_get_record in PHP seems to fix the timeout problem. Thanks anyway